# PHP error with exec bash shell when using cron job?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, cron

I've a bad problem with my PHP script that using a exec bash shell to run a binary from. It's ok if I run my PHP script on host or from shell like this:

```
php script.php
```

But when i use cron job to make it run frequently then I've a very big problem is that It seem like the PHP exec cannot run as normal. I run cron by the user which can run `php script.php`.

Here is my cron:

```
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/MODIS/modisdownload.php >> /home/rasdaman/testphp.txt
```

And here is 1 of my PHP script to exec (note: it seem it cannot run the binary program to get data)

```
exec("gdal_translate HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:\"" . $fileInput . "\":mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean " . $folderPath . "temp.tif");
```

How can I fix this problem? Please help!

OK, thank Sal00m for editting my question. The problem is that PHP exec need full path to binary program like this (/usr/local/bin/gdalinfo filename input). But How can I fix by only use gdalinfo (not need to show fullpath).

Comment: It is probably path issue, are you sure `gdal_translate` is in `$PATH`?

Comment: does your cli php have access to the necessary libraries ?

Comment: And what exactly happens or doesn't happen? Consider that the script may be running as a completely different user with different permissions and different environment configuration as cron.

Comment: as @deceze said you might be running as a different user output the errors to a txt file maybe to see

Comment: OK, thank Sal00m for editting my question. The problem is that PHP exec need full path to binary program like this (/usr/local/bin/gdalinfo filename input). But How can I fix by only use gdalinfo (not need to show fullpath).

Answer (score 2):

2 Options:

```
*/2 * * * * php /usr/bin/php /var/www/MODIS/modisdownload.php >> /home/rasdaman/testphp.txt
```

(Replace /usr/bin/php by your `php5-cli` binary (full path).)

Or add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/full/path/gdal_translate HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:\"" . $fileInput . "\":mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean " . $folderPath . "temp.tif");
```

Add the full path to the `exec` or add the `PATH` to environment using [`putenv()`](http://php.net/putenv)
(Replace /usr/bin/php by your `php5-cli` binary (full path).)